# Android NDK linking, "undefined reference" When linking with a Static Lib

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk

### Environment

- android-ndk-r10c
- VisualGDB
- Windows x64

### Use-case 1

- ADB Cmdline executable ( no Java / APK ) is consist of several C++ files
- Executable is compiled having "APP_STL := gnustl_static" at Application.mk
- **Executable is successfully compiled and running**

### Use-case 2

- The ADB tool of Use-case 1 is split into two separate projects

  - A static library encapsulating general purpose functionality
  - The ADB Tool minus the functionality moved out to the static lib
- Executable & static Lib are compiled having "APP_STL := gnustl_static" at Application.mk
- ADB Exe is compiled having LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(PATH_TO_STATIC_LIB) -lstaticlib
- **Compilation fail with "undefined reference to `std::terminate()'" Linker error**

### Problem at hand

When compiling all CPP files as one project all goes fine, no linker error.
When spiting the logic into a thin executable and a staticlib (that the executable is linked against ) I get an "undefined reference to `std::terminate()'" Linker error.

It seems to me as if "gnustl_static" is not linked with the executable although "APP_STL := gnustl_static" is specified...

What am I missing here? Is there any way to force 'gnustl_static' to link ?

### The make files for reference:

**Makefile where all files are part of the same executable (WORKING)**

Application.mk

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_ABI := all
APP_CFLAGS := -std=gnu++11
APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=gnu++11
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := ScreenCapSvc
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ScreenCapSvc.cpp SnapshotController.cpp SimpleTCPStream.cpp SocketsServer.cpp uuids.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := 
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := 
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := 
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_CFLAGS := 
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := 
LOCAL_LDFLAGS := 
COMMON_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES)
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

**Makefiles where files are split into a static lib and executable that links against the lib 
(NOT WORKING)**

Executable Application.mk

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_ABI := all
APP_CFLAGS := -std=gnu++11
APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=gnu++11
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9
```

Executable Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := ScreenCapSvc
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ScreenCapSvc.cpp SnapshotController.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := 
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := 
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := 
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -L$(PATH_TO_STATIC_LIB) -lCollections_statis
LOCAL_CFLAGS := 
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := 
LOCAL_LDFLAGS := 
COMMON_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES)
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Static Lib Application.mk

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_ABI := all
APP_CFLAGS := -std=gnu++11
APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=gnu++11
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9
APP_MODULES := Collections-static Collections-shared
```

Static Lib Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := Collections-shared
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := SimpleTCPStream.cpp SocketsServer.cpp uuids.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES :=
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES :=
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES :=
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_CFLAGS :=
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS :=
LOCAL_LDFLAGS :=
COMMON_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES)
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := Collections-static
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  $(COMMON_SRC_FILES)
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a bug in the NDK build system, but it is an issue with how you are using it.

If you run `ndk-build V=1`, you see the actual commands that it tries to execute, and you'd see that it already tries to link in gnustl_static, but it links it in before linking in your own static library. The linker only tries libraries in the order they are specified on the linker command line, which means that it won't try to use the earlier specified gnustl_static library to resolve undefined references from a later library.

The correct solution here is to not use `LOCAL_LDLIBS` for forcing linking to a static library, but use the NDK provided infrastructure for linking to static libraries. That is, change your executable Android.mk like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE           := ScreenCapSvc
LOCAL_SRC_FILES        := ScreenCapSvc.cpp SnapshotController.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := Collections_static
LOCAL_LDLIBS           := -llog
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := Collections_static
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(PATH_TO_STATIC_LIB)/libCollections_static.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

This way, you include the static library into the build of the executable in the same way regardless if the static library is built as part of the same build, or is a prebuilt library.

This syntax also allows you to add `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES` in the section for the static library, to add the right include path when building the executable, without having to manually add it to section for the executable.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that indeed although "APP_STL := gnustl_static" is strictly specified at Application.mk of the Executable it is not really linked, to force gnustl_static to link I have added the following to LOCAL_LDLIBS of Android.mk

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L$(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI) -lgnustl_static
```

Seems to me like a bug in the NDK build system...